# How do I use Python to link a certain track from a soundcloud playlist?

Tags: python, python-2.7, soundcloud

What I am doing is making a reddit bot that posts a specific track from the playlist as a reddit comment. All I need now is a way to grab the specific track. The track will be a different track from the same playlist which I post daily.

```
import urllib

site = urllib.urlopen('https://soundcloud.com/bhaisukhasinghuk/sets/daily-english-hukamnama-katha').read()
word = str(input('Track Number: '))
if word in site:
    print(word)
else:
    print(word, "not found")
```

I tried this to find the numbered track I needed for the day. However the playlist is too long and the track with the number 697 cannot be found although it exists. So how can I get around this?